# How to delete a bitmap image which is stored on the sd card in android

Tags: android

In my application I have a grid view of images and when a user clicks an image then it will open the image in fullscreen.  The images are loaded from the SD card as follows:

```
File sdDir = new File("mnt/sdcard/Pictures");
File[] sdDirFiles = sdDir.listFiles();
for(File singleFile : sdDirFiles) {
    String filePath = singleFile.getAbsolutePath();
Bitmap bmp = scaleBitmap(filePath);
photos.add(bmp);
}
mThumbIds = photos.toArray(new Bitmap[(photos.size())]);
```

}

Scale bitmap is a method which decodes each file into a bitmap and then scales the bitmap before returning it.

I then have another Activity which loads the images fullscreen once they have been clicked.  I have a menu button "Delete", from which I would like to delete the file on the sdcard which represents the bitmap I see on the screen.

The problem I have is that there is no way to get the file name from the Bitmap object, so therefore I cannot delete the file.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could extend the Bitmap class and add a filename field.  Or, you could pass the filename to your new activity in the intent bundle.

Comment: If it works for you, please accept the answer.  Alternatively, if you need more help I can post some code...cheers

Comment: If you could post some code to help then that would be great thanks.  The photos object in my code is an ArrayList<Bitmap>, hope this helps, thanks